# How to use the RenderTransform to control the orientation of a TextBlock

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-7, rendertransform

I want to make a `TextBlock` shown vertically, just like the username in the Windows Phone built-in email app:

[image]

And my XAML code is:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <Grid.Background>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="{StaticResource Status_Background}" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
    </Grid.Background>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="80"/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ProgressBar x:Name="progressBar" IsIndeterminate="True" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Visibility="Collapsed" Margin="0,6"/>
    <StackPanel>
        <Image x:Name="headerImage" Margin="0,12"  Width="70" Height="70" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
        <TextBlock Text="userName" x:Name="userName" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="0" 
                   FontSize="50" Foreground="{StaticResource Status_UserName}"
                   Width="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
            <TextBlock.RenderTransform>
                <RotateTransform Angle="-90" CenterX="80" CenterY="70"/>        
            </TextBlock.RenderTransform>
        </TextBlock>
    </StackPanel>
    <ScrollViewer Grid.Column="1" Height="Auto">
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

The result is:

[image]

The `TextBlock` didn't show up in the right place, how could I modify the XAML code?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that render transforms are applied *after* layout, as described [in this blog post](http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/blog/colin/2008/12/layouttransform-vs-rendertransform-whats-the-difference/). You need to bring your `TextBlock` out of the `StackPanel` and ensure that it is in the top left of the screen, then rotate it.

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" >
    <Grid.Background>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="{StaticResource Status_Background}" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
    </Grid.Background>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="80"/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <TextBlock Text="userName" x:Name="userName" FontSize="50"  Foreground="{StaticResource Status_UserName}" Width="auto"
               HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
             <TextBlock.RenderTransform>
               <RotateTransform Angle="-90" CenterX="80" CenterY="70"/>        
          </TextBlock.RenderTransform>
    </TextBlock>

    <ProgressBar x:Name="progressBar" IsIndeterminate="True" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Visibility="Collapsed" Margin="0,6" />
    <StackPanel>
        <Image x:Name="headerImage" Margin="0,12"  Width="70" Height="70" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>            
    </StackPanel>
    <ScrollViewer Grid.Column="1" Height="auto">

    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Thanks ColinE, you've helped me a lot BTW, do you know how to implement a pull-down-to-refresh listbox in mango? I've tried designing this listbox, but couldn't find a good method.

Comment: @ellic if my answer has helped, please upvote. Regarding a pull-to-refresh ListBox, try the following: http://danielvaughan.org/post/Scroll-Based-Data-Loading-in-Windows-Phone-7.aspx

Comment: Hi, ColinE. I've checked that post, but it doesn't meet my need. I want that the listbox is scrolled top, when the listbox is pulled down, a panel will show up, indicating "if the user keep pulling down, the listbox will refresh its data". something like that.

Answer (score 1):

I would approach it by using a translate and a rotate transform together. The rotate -90 to rotate to vertical and the translate to move it the correct place (i.e. anchor the new top left rather than the new bottom left)

Like this...

```
  <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" >               
      <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
           <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
           <ColumnDefinition/>
       </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
       <ProgressBar x:Name="progressBar" IsIndeterminate="True" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Visibility="Collapsed" Margin="0,6" />
       <StackPanel>
            <Image x:Name="headerImage" Margin="0,12"   HorizontalAlignment="Center" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
            <TextBlock Text="userName" x:Name="userName" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="0" FontSize="50"  Foreground="{StaticResource Status_UserName}" Width="225.100006103516"
               HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
                  <TextBlock.RenderTransform>
                     <CompositeTransform CenterY="0" CenterX="0" Rotation="-90" TranslateY="{Binding Width, ElementName=userName}"/>        
                  </TextBlock.RenderTransform>
            </TextBlock>
       </StackPanel>           
   </Grid>
```